# Keras show MemoryError at model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I keep getting MemoryError without additional explanation from Keras at model.fit(), no matter how small the number of neurons or batch size. Does anyone have any idea what error does this error refer to or how to fix this?

Error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ideapad/Dropbox/TA/preprocessTA/kerass.py", line 32, in <module>
    model.fit(np.array(fd.dataTrain), np.array(fd.outputTrain), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=100, verbose=1)
MemoryError
```

Code:

```
import fetchData as fd
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, LSTM, Dropout, Embedding

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(num_input, num_output))
model.add(LSTM(neuron_1))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(num_output))
model.add(Activation(activation_function))

model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=optimizer_function, metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(np.array(fd.dataTrain), np.array(fd.outputTrain), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=100, verbose=1)
score = model.evaluate(np.array(fd.dataTest), np.array(fd.outputTest))
print(score)
```

Comment: How big are fd.dataTrain and fd.outputTrain? And how much RAM memory is available?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro fd.dataTrain is less than 50 mB, fd.outputTrain is less than 30 mB. There are around 3.4 gB free RAM.

Comment: I am not talking about Megabytes, but like number of elements or shapes (if they are tensors).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro fd.dataTrain is 2d list 100554, 8. fd.outputTrain is 2d list 100554, 2

Comment: Well its failing when you convert to a numpy array, so its probably too big, but its very hard to say what exactly is wrong without all the information.

Comment: Replace `np.array` by `np.asarray`. This will not copy the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Error in numpy, solved when using np.asarray. Thank you @MatiasValdnegro and @Idavid.